# Use 2 different framework versions in one project

Tags: ios, xcode, nest-api

Is it even possible to use 2 versions of same framework in my XCode project?

I need `Firebase.framework` pre google version (to connect to NEST API) as well as new one (used for analytics now).
I've tried to create an intermediate `LegacyFirebase.Framework` which is compiled with an old `Firebase.framework` file.

```
#import "LegacyFirebase.h"
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>

@interface LegacyFirebase () {
@private
    Firebase * fb;
}
@end

@implementation LegacyFirebase

-(instancetype)init:(NSString *) urlString  {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        fb = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:urlString];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)authorize:(NSString *) token completion: (void (^)(NSError *error , id data))block {
    [fb authWithCredential:token withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, id data) {
        block(error, data);
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        block(error, nil);
    }];
}

-(void)subscribe: (void (^)(NSDictionary* data))block {
    [fb observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        block(snapshot.value);
    }];
}
```

But when I added it to my project, which already contains new `Firebase.framework` included -- LegacyFirebase seems to use new one.

EDIT/DONE:

Managed to create correct intermediate `LegacyFirebase.Framework`. I can use it in my project and have no conflicts.

Comment: the question is: why...?

Comment: @holex, Need two separate login sessions at the same time. New is configured for Firebase Analytics, while an old one will be used to access NEST API just by provided token.

Comment: Are you only using one target to do this?